# Conditional print statement prints the wrong message

Tags: python

Here is an example:

```
my_name_is_anna = True
my_name_is_david = not my_name_is_anna

self_introduction = "Hello, my name is " + ("Anna!" if my_name_is_anna else "David!")
print(self_introduction) # Prints "Hello, my name is Anna!"

my_name_is_anna = False
print(self_introduction) # Still prints "Hello, my name is Anna!"
```

After setting `my_name_is_anna` to `False`, I want to print `"Hello, my name is David!"` instead. Is there any concise way to do so **without** creating a separate function like the following?

```
def write_self_introduction(my_name_is_anna):
    return "Hello, my name is " + ("Anna!" if my_name_is_anna else "David!")

print(write_self_introduction(my_name_is_anna=True)) # Prints "Hello, my name is Anna!"
print(write_self_introduction(my_name_is_anna=False)) # Prints "Hello, my name is David!"
```

Comment: Your function is a clean solution. +1 for not using a global variable.

Comment: You can also use lambdas, I updated answer. This will keep you in local scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition gets evaluated right away and is converted to string. If you want to recalculate it - create a function or a lambda

#### function:

```
my_name_is_anna = False
def self_introduction():
    return "Hello, my name is " + ("Anna!" if my_name_is_anna else "David!")

print(self_introduction())
```

#### lambda:

```
my_name_is_anna = False
self_introduction = lambda:"Hello, my name is " + ("Anna!" if my_name_is_anna else "David!")

print(self_introduction())
```

Comment: *Thank you!* The `lambda` keyword is exactly what I want. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes.